# Target API level 31 app not downloadable from Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

We have an old android app (built with Cordova) that recently was updated to target API level 31. However, the app cannot be installed from Play Store on an Android 13 device due to "This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android", despite double checking the target API level of our bundle in the Play Console.

I tried downloading our app from the App Store, but encountered a "This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android" message on a Sony Xperia running android 13. I expected to be able to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around 24h after the version became available on Play Store, the status on the store updated and I could install it.

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK API level 31 is Android 12.
Android 13 has the API level 33.

That might be the problem.